# Trying to append a string within a shell script using python

Tags: python, bash, docker

I'm trying to change the value of "dockerversion=" in this bash script.

```
# Docker Variables
containerid=$(docker ps -qf "name=vaultwarden")
imageid=$(docker images -q vaultwarden/server)

dockerversion=1
---------------

# Stop/RM Image
docker stop $containerid
docker rm $containerid
docker rmi $imageid
```

I'm using python and currently am at

```
# Pull Portainer Version
url = 'https://github.com/dani-garcia/vaultwarden/releases/latest'
r = requests.get(url)
version = r.url.split('/')[-1]

# Pull Current Version
with open('vaultwarden-update', 'r') as vaultwarden:
    fileversion = vaultwarden.readlines()
    vcurrentversion = re.sub(r'dockerversion=', '', fileversion[14])

# Check who is higher
if version > vcurrentversion:
    with open('vaultwarden-update', '') as vaultwarden:
        for line in fileversion[14]:
            vaultwarden.write(re.sub(re.escape(vcurrentversion), version))
```

I basically want python to check the github releases, see if there's a change, compare that number to the bash script variable, update that within the bash-script and run the script.

The # Check who is higher
Won't work as I need to keep the entire other script file. Just mainly looking for ways to append/change a value through python. Dynamically.

Any thoughts?

(this is literally my first python script)

Comment: Can you honor `$dockerversion` from the containing environment, if it's provided; use `${dockerversion:-1}` where you use it?  Or, can you use the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) directly instead of using Python to invoke a shell script to invoke Docker?

Answer (score 1):

I took your code and changed it just enough to do what you want it to do. You would need to do some value validations, so that you could log and exit before execution comes to the final part where you rewrite your file (you don't want to open and rewrite if there is nothing to rewrite with).

```
import re
import requests
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

# Pull Portainer Version
url = 'https://github.com/dani-garcia/vaultwarden/releases/latest'
r = requests.get(url)
github_version = r.url.split('/')[-1]

# Pull Current Version
with open('vaultwarden-update') as vaultwarden:
    file_content = vaultwarden.read()
    file_match = re.search(r'(dockerversion=([0-9.]*))', file_content)
    file_version = file_match.group(2)

# Check who is higher
if LooseVersion(github_version) > LooseVersion(file_version):
    print(f'github version ({github_version}) > file version ({file_version})')
    with open('vaultwarden-update', 'w') as vaultwarden:
        new_file_content = file_content.replace(file_match.group(1), f'dockerversion={github_version}')
        vaultwarden.write(new_file_content)
```

Currently for your content, it outputs:

```
github version (1.23.0) > file version (1)
```

Comment: ty so much! been literally trying this all day, i am absolute noob lol. 

appreciate it

Comment: No worries, @George, glad if that helped