# Calling a bash script from python

Tags: python, bash, docker

I've been trying to make a python script that works as a sort of listener for updates - so if the github release changes, update the file. call/run the script

```py
# Pull Vaultwarden Version
url = 'https://github.com/dani-garcia/vaultwarden/releases/latest'
r = requests.get(url)
vwgithub_version = r.url.split('/')[-1]
vcommand = 'bash vaultwarden-update'

# Pull Current Version for VW
with open('vaultwarden-update') as vaultwarden:
    vw_file_content = vaultwarden.read()
    vw_file_match = re.search(r'(dockerversion=([0-9.]*))', vw_file_content)
    vw_file_version = vw_file_match.group(2)

# Check who is higher
if LooseVersion(vwgithub_version) == LooseVersion(vw_file_version):
    # print(f'github version ({github_version}) > file version ({file_version})')
    with open('vaultwarden-update', 'w') as vaultwarden:
        vw_new_file_content = vw_file_content.replace(vw_file_match.group(1), f'dockerversion={vwgithub_version}')
        vaultwarden.write(vw_new_file_content)
        subprocess.call([vcommand], shell=True)
```

Subprocess is imported, and I've also tried os (which returns a "sh text file busy" error.)

It runs and finishes, but it doesn't seem run the scripts. Any thoughts. Scripts are started with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (also have been made executable)

if version == version is just for testing, but hoping to keep it like this for now. I can always swap to the docker SDK as someone has previously mentioned to me too.

Thanks!

Comment: thats the script it's meant to try and run, I've tried it within `subprocess.call(['bash', 'vaultwarden-update'])` haven't got it to run at all yet. Any thoughts?

Comment: tried vcommand = 'bash ./vaultwarden-update' ?  instead of vcommand = 'bash vaultwarden-update' ?

Comment: yeah, ive tried both. Doesn't seem to call it. Returns no errors, but just doesn't run

Comment: does your python script have adequate privileges to run the script?

Comment: It must be an issue with the code itself, because if i run a command to call the script standalone, it works....

Comment: Is your script still open by python while invoking it ? Try exit with open statement before subprocess

Comment: Does closing the file before trying to run it help (move `subprocess.call()` outside the `with open()` block)?  In [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70105255) you were trying to use this technique to set environment variables; [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and similar calls can also directly set environment variables, which might be much simpler and safer.

Comment: thanks david! you were right. I've solved it now, tysm. learning so much!

Comment: Thanks david !! Cmon I spotted it first !! Maybe is written in very poor english but solution was there